# Highlight color switching

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which I want to use but its color switching function doesn't work. It only highlights in green color. I would like to use other colors as well. I am hoping that this is easy fix, and someone can tell me what to do. thanks. I know the code is not neat, but I hope you can still see the problem in jquery. I am no expert on this. thanks. https://jsfiddle.net/msruauvL/

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.selector').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', check); 
});
    $('.all').each(function() {
       $(this).on('click', all); 
    });

function all(event) {

        if($(this).is(':checked')){  $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","checked");
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","");
    }

    //$('.selector').prop("checked", this.name === "SelectAll");

    check(event);
}

function check(event) {
    var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function () {
        return this.name
    }).get()
    $('td').removeClass("highlight").filter(function () {
        return $.inArray($(this).text(), checked) >= 0
    }).addClass("highlight")
    if ($(this).is(".selector"))
        $('.all').not(this).prop("checked", false)

}


 $( "#Hidden").on( "click", function() {
        $(".selector").toggle();
    });


});
```

Comment: It only highlights green because that's the colour you've set on the `.highlight` class. There is no code which is dependant on the selected colour in the picker. Could you please describe exactly what you are attempting to do, as I'm certain the code can be made much more simple.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I found the answer, thanks for your interest. I basically wanted to switch colors from the color palette.

Comment: Glad you got your answer, although I'd still suggest you submit this to codereview.stackexchange.com, as there are a lot of ways you can make the code more succinct.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I didn't know about code review. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your **highlight class** in the css file explicitly sets the background color to green.

Here is a quick fix, where I don't rely on the class, but on the background color of the `td` elements.

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.selector').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', check); 
});
    $('.all').each(function() {
       $(this).on('click', all); 
    });

function all(event) {
    
        if($(this).is(':checked')){  $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","checked");
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","");
    }
    
    //$('.selector').prop("checked", this.name === "SelectAll");
    
    check(event);
}

function check(event) {
    var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function () {
        return this.name
    }).get()
    $('td').css('background', '#fff').filter(function () {
        return $.inArray($(this).text(), checked) >= 0
    }).css('background', $('#nextColor').val())
    if ($(this).is(".selector"))
        $('.all').not(this).prop("checked", false)

}

    
 $( "#Hidden").on( "click", function() {
        $(".selector").toggle();
    });
 

});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
*
{
    margin: 3;
    padding: 3;
}

html, body, .Container
{
    height: 98%;
}

    .Container:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

.Header
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.Content
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .Content:after
    {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }

.Wrapper
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 500px;
 height: 100%;
}
    .Wrapper > div
    {
        height: 100%;
    }

.LeftContent
{
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
 width: 600px;
}

.mainContent
{
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 800px;
  
}

.highlight {background:#9ac99d;}

.selector {
    display: none;
}


tr.border_bottom td {
  border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}


 table.tableizer-table {
 border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
    border-collapse:collapse; /* Keeps the table lines like in excel */
    table-layout:fixed;   /* Fits the table in the screen */
} 
.tableizer-table td {
 padding: 6px;
 margin: 6px;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.tableizer-table th {
 background-color: #FFFFFF; 
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3><input id="nextColor" type="color" value="#9ac99d"> Parameters:</h3>
 
 <div>
 

 
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
             <label>                
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="5" class="selector" />5</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="7" class="selector" />7</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="9" class="selector" />9</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="10" class="selector" />10</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="19" class="selector" />19</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="23" class="selector" />23</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="35" class="selector" />35</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="37" class="selector" />37</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="40" class="selector" />40</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="43" class="selector" />43</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="44" class="selector" />44</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="46" class="selector" />46</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="51" class="selector" />51</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="52" class="selector" />52</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="54" class="selector" />54</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="55" class="selector" />55</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="60" class="selector" />60</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="61" class="selector" />61</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="62" class="selector" />62</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="70" class="selector" />70</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="74" class="selector" />74</label><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="75" class="selector" />75</label> </form> 
                    </div>
         <div>
         
                        
       <table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>18</th><th>20</th><th>22</th><th>29</th><th>30</th><th>32</th><th>33</th><th>34</th><th>38</th><th>39</th><th>51</th><th>56</th><th>57</th><th>60</th><th>61</th><th>63</th><th>72</th><th>75</th><th>77</th><th>80</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>9</td><td>12</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>26</td><td>28</td><td>30</td><td>42</td><td>48</td><td>55</td><td>61</td><td>75</td><td>77</td></tr>
</tbody></table>             
                    
                     </div>
```

What I basically replaced was `$('td').removeClass("highlight")` by `$('td').css('background', '#fff')` to reset the background color, and then `.addClass("highlight")` by `.css('background', $('#nextColor').val())` to give them whatever background color is selected on the color field.

Answer (score 1):

Removed class "Highlight" and used css() of jquery change selected color.

function check(event) {

```
var colorH = $("#nextColor").val()
var defaultcolor = '#FFF'; 

var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function () {
    return this.name
}).get()
$('td').css({'background':defaultcolor}).filter(function () {
    return $.inArray($(this).text(), checked) >= 0
}).css({'background':colorH}); 
if ($(this).is(".selector"))
    $('.all').not(this).prop("checked", false)
```

}